# fancybox beforeclose allow close when condition met

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog, fancybox

I have a fancybox that opens an iFrame where a user can modify form data.  I want to make it so that if the fancybox is attempted to be closed that the user is asked if they wish to save any changes made.  I am wanting to do this using a jQuery UI Dialog box with buttons "Yes", "No" and "Cancel".  This dialog is generated and displayed using the fancybox beforeClose callback.  I have been able to prevent the fancybox from closing while the dialog is displayed by returning false, my question is, how can I now close the fancybox?  Using $.fancybox.close() simply triggers the fancybox beforeClose callback again (looping).

My Code:

```
$.fancybox.open({
    href:'/index.php?task=details_movie',
    type:'iframe',
    padding:10,
    minHeight: '90%',
    beforeClose: function() {
        if ($("#dialog-confirm").length == 0) {
            $("body").append('<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Save changes?"><p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin: 0 7px 20px 0;"></span>Do you wish to save any changes made to the details of this movie?</p></div>');
            $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
                modal:true,
                buttons: [ 
                    { 
                        text: "Yes", 
                        click: function() { 
                            alert("Yes"); // perform save actions
                            $("#dialog-confirm").remove();
                        } 
                    },
                    { 
                        text: "No", 
                        click: function() { 
                            $.fancybox.close(); // this creates the loop back to beforeClose callback
                            $("#dialog-confirm").remove();
                        } 
                    },
                    { 
                        text: "Cancel", 
                        click: function() { 
                            $("#dialog-confirm").remove();
                            return false;
                        } 
                    }
                ]
            });
            $(".ui-widget-overlay").css({"z-index": 99999});
            $(".ui-dialog").css({"z-index": 100000});
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading the post below I have been able to make the following changes to my code to achieve the desired result:

[How can I stop a fancyBox from closing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8652024/how-can-i-stop-a-fancybox-from-closing)

1. Changed from using beforeClose callback to afterShow callback
2. Unbound click event from fancybox close button
3. Created a new click event for the fancybox close button with a function containing my previous beforeClose function

In this way the fancybox close button will now trigger the jQuery UI Dialog and depending on the button selected in this dialog will now be able to trigger the $.fancybox.close() function without it triggering the beforeClose loop as was my initial issue.

I also disabled the ability to close fancybox using the escape key to force the user to click the close button.

My updated code:

```
$.fancybox.open({
    href:'/index.php?task=details_movie',
    type:'iframe',
    padding:10,
    minHeight: '90%',
    keys : {
        close  : null // prevent close on escape pressed
    },
    afterShow: function() {
        $(".fancybox-close").unbind(); // unbind events from close button
        $(".fancybox-close").click(function() { // create own click event
            if ($("#dialog-confirm").length == 0) {
                $("body").append('<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Save changes?"><p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin: 0 7px 20px 0;"></span>Do you wish to save any changes made to the details of this movie?</p></div>');
                $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
                    modal:true,
                    buttons: [ 
                        { 
                            text: "Yes", 
                            click: function() { 
                                // perform save functions
                                $("#dialog-confirm").remove();
                                $.fancybox.close();
                            } 
                        },
                        { 
                            text: "No", 
                            click: function() { 
                                $("#dialog-confirm").remove();
                                $.fancybox.close();
                            } 
                        },
                        { 
                            text: "Cancel", 
                            click: function() { 
                                $("#dialog-confirm").remove();
                            } 
                        }
                    ]
                });
                $(".ui-widget-overlay").css({"z-index": 99999});
                $(".ui-dialog").css({"z-index": 100000});
            }
        });
    }
});
```